# Python while loop terminating early

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a Python program that churns out a solved sudoku puzzle. It randomly generates coordinates for a tile, and if that tile already has a number in it, it tries again. It then generates a number between 1 and 9 to put there, and if that number isn't already in that row, column, or section, it'll assign the value and add those coordinates to the list of occupied tiles. Once all the tiles are filled, it's supposed to exit the loop and return the completed grid.

The trouble is, it's always stopping for no reason after about 70 loops, causing the program to freeze.

Here is the code for the function I'm talking about:

```
def populate(grid):
    usedCoords = []
    populated = False
    while not populated:
        x = random.randrange(len(grid))
        y = random.randrange(len(grid))
        while [x,y] in usedCoords:
            x = random.randrange(len(grid))
            y = random.randrange(len(grid))
        value = random.randrange(1, len(grid) + 1)
        if not rowCheck(grid, x, y, value) and not columnCheck(grid, x, y, value) and not squareCheck(grid, x, y, value):
            grid[x][y] = value
            usedCoords.append([x,y])
            print(len(usedCoords))
        if len(usedCoords) == len(grid) ** 2:
            populated = True
    return grid
```

And here is the code for the functions it references:

```
def rowCheck(grid, x, y, value):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        if not i == x:
            if grid[i][y] == value:
                return True
    return False

def columnCheck(grid, x, y, value):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        if not i==y:
            if grid[x][i] == value:
                return True
    return False

def squareCheck(grid, x, y, value):
    grid2 = [0] * (sectionSide) #new grid for the specific section
    for i in range(len(grid2)):
        grid2[i] = [0] * sectionSide
    for i in range(x - (sectionSide - 1), x + sectionSide): #scanning only nearby coordinates
        for j in range(y - (sectionSide - 1), y + sectionSide):
            try:
                if i // sectionSide == x // sectionSide and j // sectionSide == y // sectionSide:
                    grid2[i][j] = grid[x][y]
            except IndexError:
                pass
    for i in range(len(grid2)):
        for j in range(len(grid2[i])):
            if grid2[i][j] == value and not (i == x and j == y):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Are you sure your loop's terminating early, rather than *not* terminating at all?

Answer (score 3):

There may be other issues, but a big problem with your code is that it has no way to backtrack if it finds it's created a board state that cannot be solved. Consider what would happen if your code put the following values on the first two rows of the board:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3
```

The numbers that have been placed so far are all legal, but there is no number that you can put in the last space of the second row. I'd guess that your code is eventually getting stuck when it creates a bunch of board positions like this, which cannot take any value. If there are no legal moves left it can make, it will keep on looping forever.

You need a more sophisticated algorithm to avoid this issue.